# Django + django-rest-framework-simplejwt protect view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just installed `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` in a Django project and if I send an invalid `Authentication Bearer <<token>>` header, it blocks my request with 401 code. Which is the expected behavior. The problem is that if I remove the `Authentication` header, I can access my view, so it's unprotected.

How can I protect the view to return 401 if there is no `Authentication` header?

Here's the view code:

```
class AuthTestView(views.APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get(self, request):
        response_data = {
            'result': 'Restricted access test ok.',
        }
        return Response(data=response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class AuthTestView(views.APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated] 
    def get(self, request):
        response_data = {
            'result': 'Restricted access test ok.',
        }
        return Response(data=response_data
```